# :first-child selector selects more than one children

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to apply a style to ONLY the very first child of an element. I'm using :first-child in the css to achieve this, but it looks like it's not the behaviour I'm looking for.

Take the following markup as example:

```
<ul class="myUl">
    <ul class="mySubUl">
        <li>foo0</li>
        <li>foo1</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="mySubUl">
        <li>foo2</li>
        <li>foo3</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
======================
<ul class="myUl">
    <li>foo0</li>
    <li>foo1</li>
    <ul class="mySubUl">
        <li>foo2</li>
        <li>foo3</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

and this simple CSS:

```
ul.myUl li:first-child {
    color: red;
}
```

Live fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bsSDh/1/

This applies not only to the first child of the `ul.myUl` elements, but also to the first child of `ul.subUl`. I would have expected this behaviour if the CSS selector was `ul li:first-child` (which works), but since I'm adding a class to the selector I'm expecting to apply that style only to the very first child.

Why does the style applies not only to the first child? Am I missing something about `first-child` specs or using the selector in the wrong way?

Comment: each of your sub-`<ul>`s has a new `:first-child`. The selector does not reference to any specific ancestor element, but just to the immediate parent.

Comment: You should first get your markup right. A `ul` element is not allowed as a child of a `ul` element.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela good point, I wrote this example too fast :) in my  actual code the inner ul is wrapped inside another li, but thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need an additional [child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) element like this:

```
ul.myUl > li:first-child {
    color: red;
}
```

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bsSDh/3/)

Your selector selects any `<li>` below `ul.myUL`, that is a first child. As this references only to the immediate parent and not any other ancestor, all those other `<li>` match as well.

**EDIT**

After your comment, I assume, that you will need a somehow complexer selector like this:

```
ul.myUl > li:first-child,
ul.myUl > ul:first-child > li:first-child {
        color: red;
}
```

Comment: I thought of this, but it doesn't work on the first of the two examples, that's why I added two different cases

Comment: @LorenzoMarcon Then you will probably need to target both cases separately.

Comment: This works. Given that definition of first-child, I guess there's no way to simplify it in a single rule, so this is the only way (in css) to do what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The selector

```
ul.myUl li:first-child
```

selects any `li:first-child` below any `ul.myUl` (i.e. first child of *any* parent inside the `ul`). Instead you might want to select a direct child via

```
ul.myUl > li:first-child
```

or even

```
ul.myUl > ul.subUl:first-child > li:first-child
```

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the differences between the [Child Combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators) (a direct child) and the [Descendant Combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#descendant-combinators) (any element contained).

You should use this two selectors to achieve the result wanted on the two known cases:

```
ul.myUl > ul:first-child > li:first-child {
    color: red;
}

ul.myUl > li:first-child {
    color: red;
}
```

<kbd>[**Running Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AndreaLigios/bsSDh/5/)</kbd>